# .htaccess file blocks Payment Notification from paypal

Tags: .htaccess, filter, paypal, payment-gateway, payment-processing

Here is an example of $_POST data from paypal's IPN:

```
cmd=_notify-validate
&test_ipn=1
&payment_type=instant
&payment_date=18%3A49%3A30+Nov+01%2C+2010+PDT
&payment_status=Completed
&address_status=unconfirmed
&payer_status=unverified
&first_name=John
&last_name=Smith
&payer_email=buyer
%40paypalsandbox.com
&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01
&address_name=John+Smith
&address_country=United+States
&address_country_code=US
&address_zip=95131
&address_state=CA
&address_city=San+Jose
&address_street=123%2C+any+street
&business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com
&receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com
&receiver_id=TESTSELLERID1
&residence_country=US
&item_name=something
&item_number=AK-1234
&quantity=1
&shipping=3.04
&tax=2.02
&mc_currency=USD
&mc_fee=0.44
&mc_gross=10
&mc_gross_1=10
&txn_type=web_accept
&txn_id=30112149
&notify_version=2.1
&custom=10points
&charset=windows-1252
&verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7Zyy8mw-cdzleMW.oxFXxXE
```

When I try to send this with my .htaccess file I get an 403 error.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  ^(HEAD|TRACE|DELETE|TRACK) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}     ^.*(\\r|\\n|%0A|%0D).* [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}    ^(.*)(<|>|’|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}     ^.*(<|>|’|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}     ^/(,|;|:|<|>|”>|”<|/|\\\.\.\\).{0,9999}.* [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(java|curl|wget).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(winhttp|HTTrack|clshttp|archiver|loader|email|harvest|extract|grab|miner).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(libwww-perl|curl|wget|python|nikto|scan).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(<|>|’|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    ^.*(;|<|>|’|”|\)|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*(/\*|union|select|insert|cast|set|declare|drop|update|md5|benchmark).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    ^.*(localhost|loopback|127\.0\.0\.1).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    ^.*\.[A-Za-z0-9].* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    ^.*(<|>|’|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

How do I change the .htaccess file to make it allow the $_POST data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the sinner:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [OR]

Answer (score 0):

You can enable logging on the rewrite engine. (Just for debugging.)  You will see the exact rule where is dies.

Comment: adding RewriteLog "rewrite.log" to .htaccess gives a server error.. damn

Comment: Error that the log is disabled, or that you are writing to a location u dont have permision for?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this line:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    ^.*\.[A-Za-z0-9].* [NC,OR]
```

I believe that is matching on any full stop following by an alpha-numeric character in the query string. Seems like that would fail requests like "shipping=3.04"